# How to prove $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

If $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$ exists, then $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$.

**My attempt:**

If either $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=+\infty$ or $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=+\infty$, then there's nothing to prove, hence we assume that $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=A$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=B$, where $A>+\infty$ and $B>+\infty$. Furthermore there exists $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n<A+\varepsilon /2$ and $b_n<A+\varepsilon /2$. Let $N:=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then $$\forall n\geq N:a_n+b_n<A+\varepsilon /2 +B+ \varepsilon /2 =A+B+\varepsilon$$

We chose $\varepsilon$ arbitrary, thus we have $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)= A+B$

Comment: I think this is false? $(a_n)_n = (0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots), (b_n)_n = (1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots)$

Comment: If $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ then lim inf $a_n$ = lim inf $b_n = -1$ but lim inf $(a_n+b_n)=0$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107580/prove-that-underline-lim-a-n-underline-lim-b-n-leq-underline

Comment: Did you mean  lim inf ($a_n+b_n)\color{red}\ge $ lim inf $a_n$ + lim inf $b_n,$ or lim $(a_n+b_n)= $ lim $ a_n+ $ lim $b_n$?

Comment: in the first paragraph it says "If $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$ exists [...]$ - does that change anythign?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Not really. The liminf exists for any sequence bounded below (and some define to be $-\infty$ for sequences that are not). The counterexamples of mathworker21 and J. W. Tanner still work.

Comment: That's odd! Did not think that profs also make mistakes :'D

Comment: This is false. Furthermore, the falsehood of the essentially equivalent statement was pointed out yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3245771/27978.

Comment: But showing "$\geq$" does not exclude "$=$", doesn't it? Under certain circumstances "$=$" must be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You've misstated what the liminf is. You should have that for $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $N_1,N_2$ so that 
$$n \ge N_1 \implies a_n > A - \epsilon/2$$ and $$n \ge N_2 \implies b_n > B - \epsilon/2.$$
The best you can get from this is
$$n \ge \max\{N_1,N_2\} \implies A+B \le a_n + b_n + \epsilon.$$

This leads to $A+B \le \liminf (a_n + b_n)$. You can't get equality, as pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful: [Calculus - Proofs of some basic limit rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules).
The R.T.P. is a basic property for limits known as "*Sum Rule for Limits*", But the example above isn't a normal limit, it's an inferior limit. So, I think this can help: [Limit superior and limit inferior - Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Properties).
As written in that article:-

> The limit inferior satisfies [superadditivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superadditivity):
>   $$\liminf _{n\to \infty }(a_{n}+b_{n})\geq \liminf _{n\to \infty }(a_{n})+\liminf _{n\to \infty }(b_{n})$$
>   In the particular case that one of the sequences actually converges, say $a_{n}\to a$, then the inequalities above become equalities (with $\limsup _{n\to \infty }a_{n}$ or $\liminf _{n\to \infty }a_{n}$ being replaced by $a$).

I hope this helps !